# dante SOCKS5 auth process use custom script

Tags: authentication, socks, dante

Is there a way I can use my own script for auth process of dante SOCKS server? I store my passwords created with bcrypt(). Free radius isn't able to handle bcrypt() generated passwords I think, so a custom auth script would be the best solution.